# Recreate observable automatically after new data arrives

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a method which creates an observable that is the merge of multiple other observables.  Each one subscribes to a certain symbol to get its data:

```
var obs1 = dataSource
                .CreateObservable(someClass.Symbol1)
                .Select(result => ProcessData(result));

var obs2 = dataSource
                .CreateObservable(someClass.Symbol2)
                .Select(result => ProcessData(result));

var obs3 = dataSource
                .CreateObservable(someClass.Symbol3)
                .Select(result => ProcessData(result));

return Observable.Merge(obs1,obs2,obs3);
```

I subscribe to the merged observable and everything is ok.  Now, when any of the symbols is changed (someClass.Symbol 1/2/3), I would like the observable to be recreated to use the new symbol.  I can get a notification when the symbol changes.

Is there a way using RX to have the observable recreate itself automatically?  Maybe use something like TakeUntil("symbol changed") and then do something?

Not sure if this is possible, especially when using the merged observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can make an `IObservable<TSymbol> Symbol1Changed`, property that sends you the new symbol everytime it changes, then something like this will work:

```
var obs1 = someClass.Symbol1Changed
    .StartWith(someClass.Symbol1) // to start it with the current value before the first change
    .Select(newSymbol => dataSource.CreateObservable(newSymbol))
    .Switch()
    .Select(result => ProcessData(result);

var obs2 = ...
var obs3 = ...

return Observable.Merge(obs1, obs2, obs3);
```

If you use a `BehaviorSubject` for your `Symbol1` property, then you can just do:

```
var obs1 = someClass.Symbol1
    .Select(newSymbol => dataSource.CreateObservable(newSymbol))
    .Switch()
    .Select(result => ProcessData(result);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this with Rx. It's the kind of thing it has been designed to do.

What you're really describing here is that you'll have three sources of symbols that you want to trigger the processing of data for. So create the three symbol sources:

```
var symbol1s = new Subject<Symbol>();
var symbol2s = new Subject<Symbol>();
var symbol3s = new Subject<Symbol>();
```

Now define each observable like so:

```
var obs1 =
    symbol1s
        .Select(symbol =>
            dataSource
                .CreateObservable(symbol)
                .Select(result => ProcessData(result)))
        .Switch();
```

This is basically saying that with every new symbol that comes along switch to a new observable based on that symbol.

Define all three in the same way and then merge as you did before.

Then just issue a `symbol1s.OnNext(someClass.Symbol1);` (or similar) and you're good to go.

You don't have to use subjects to define your observables. You can use events or some other source if that makes more sense in your program.